# Ajax doubling GET data in single request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I seem to be having a weird issue with this Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    data : searchParams,
    dataType: "json",

    // handle a successful response
    success : function(json) {...}
```

Here's the resulting browser url:

```
http://localhost:8000/discover?event_search=gfgd&event_filter=&event_timeselect=&event_start_date=&event_end_date=&event_free_admission=False&event_after_five=False&event_kid_friendly=False&event_no_underage=False&event_location=BOUNDS%3A%2060.672585355151256%20-73.55389374789888%2018.26993602652665%20-121.01483124789888&search_type=Event
```

And here is what my server sees:

```
[11/Jul/2018 14:23:09] "GET /discover?event_search=gfgd&event_filter=&event_timeselect=&event_start_date=&event_end_date=&event_free_admission=False&event_after_five=False&event_kid_friendly=False&event_no_underage=False&event_location=BOUNDS%3A%2060.672585355151256%20-73.55389374789888%2018.26993602652665%20-121.01483124789888&search_type=Event&event_search=gfgd&event_filter=&event_timeselect=&event_start_date=&event_end_date=&event_free_admission=False&event_after_five=False&event_kid_friendly=False&event_no_underage=False&event_location=BOUNDS%3A%2061.31466023609533%20-73.43351449880555%2019.522712232892687%20-120.89445199880555&search_type=Event HTTP/1.1" 200 107
```

If I print `searchParams` to console, it correctly shows one instance of each variable, but my backened is definitely finding each one twice.

What could cause this?

Comment: How is `searchParams` being created?  Can you expand the context of the logic you have shown us?

Comment: There's a lot going on in the code.. If you are telling me that the console can display an object with a single instance of each variable but in truth have two instances of each variable, I can go back through everything and make sure it isn't being packed twice.

Comment: I'm just wanting to make sure you are not logging something that is shared at a higher scope than it needs to be, and something may be modifying it after you have logged it.  I can't say that it is not doing that.  Just the first spitball at trying to see what is going on.

Comment: Also related to what Loic said below, what is the value of the url?

Comment: either `$('#mapPage').val()` already contains the params, or you have some kind of rewriting occuring that is duplicating it before it reaches your backend. (the client would not be the cause of this)

Comment: Okay, I commented below, but I removed the url variable, as it was empty anyway, but I am still seeing the issue.

Comment: Sorry for the bad question. It really is a few hundred lines of code that is involved with building the parameters in various cases, etc. I was hoping that printing the object to the console immediately before the Ajax call would eliminate the need to unpack all of it. - Also, the browser is showing the correct URL

Comment: @Taplar I understand. This variable is just being passed from one function to the next, there isn't any global version of it.. I'm literally printing it to console, and then on the next line putting it to Ajax, and my server is getting a different URL from my browser. I guess I was hoping it was something easy about how I was building the AJAX call.

Comment: Ok, and you said the variable being passed to the url was blank.  Are there any params in the page url the ajax is originating from?  If you don't give the ajax the url it will use the url of the page.

Comment: Yep! That's my problem, isn't it. I need a valid URL to start from or else it will take the existing URL?

Comment: Possibly.  If the page url has params it may be taking those and adding on those that you give in the data.

Comment: Try setting the url to `window.location.origin + window.location.pathname`.  That should give it the pages url without the parameters

Comment: That was exactly it. I just needed to provide the base URL. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks, that was really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, when you do a GET with a url that has parameters in it already, if you give jQuery more data it will add those to the query rather than replacing the original ones.  In this case, it was grabbing the url of the page, since a url was not provided.

To fix this you can either hardcode the url without parameters, if you know the url.  Otherwise, you might try setting the url to `window.location.origin + window.location.pathname`.  This appears to build the url without the parameters.

For instance when I view this page, my browser url is

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294378/ajax-doubling-get-data-in-single-request/51294746#51294746`

But using that line of code in the console prints

`"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294378/ajax-doubling-get-data-in-single-request/51294746"`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Something has been bothering me about this. If Ajax was appending the data to the end of the current URL before sending it to the server, why was it displaying correctly in the browser's address bar? Why were those two urls different?

Comment: Ajax doesn't update the address bar.  Ajax performs a web request without affecting your current browser state.  That's the primary reason why it exists.  To allow you to make web requests without a page transition. @AdamStarrh

Comment: I see. It is definitely updating the address bar in Chrome after my search is completed. I must have hardcoded that in a long time ago and forgotten about it. I appreciate the help!